# ошибка в xml-разметке: error parsing xml:not well-formed(invalid token)

Tags: android, xml

Написал простенькое приложение вычисляющее функцию в зависимости от введенного значения(т.н. кусочно-заданная функция).

Проблема в том, что при компиляции и запуске на устройстве(планшет под управлением android 4.4, проект соответсвенно тоже создан под андроид 4.4) вылазит описанная ошибка со ссылкой на xml в котором описана форма приложения. Приложение переписывал с нуля, пересоздавал проект с копипастой содержимого, очищал и перестраивал, не помогает.

код прилагается:
xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.lab02a2andr_.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:text="введите Х:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
            android:text="sin(x^2-3) x<=-1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="(x+4)*x^2-3 -1<x<1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="cos(sqrt(x)) x>=1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />

    </RadioGroup>

    <CheckBox
        android:text="Удвоить"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" />

    <Button
        android:text="Посчитать"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="0.03" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Ответ:"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

mainActivity:

```
package com.example.lab02a2andr_;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private CheckBox cb;
private TextView tv2;
private RadioButton rb1,rb2,rb3;
private EditText et1;
private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    cb=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    rb1=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb2=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    rb3=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
    et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
            if(!hasFocus){
                Calculate();
            }
        }
    });
    rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Calculate();
        }
    });
    rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Calculate();
        }
    });
    rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Calculate();
        }
    });
    cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Calculate();
        }
    });
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Calculate();
        }
    });
}

public void Calculate(){
    String s1;
    double x,y=0;
    int var;

    s1=et1.getText().toString();
    x=Double.parseDouble(s1);


    if(rb1.isChecked()==true){
        var=1;
    }else if(rb2.isChecked()==true){
        var=2;
    }else if(rb3.isChecked()==true){
        var=3;
    }else{
        if(x<=-1) {
            var = 1;
            rb1.setChecked(true);
        }else if(x>=1){
            var=3;
            rb3.setChecked(true);
        }else{
            var=2;
            rb2.setChecked(true);
        }
    }

    switch (var){
        case 1:
            y=Math.sin(x*x-3);
            break;
        case 2:
            y=(x+4)*x*x-3;
            break;
        case 3:
            y=Math.cos(Math.sqrt(x));
            break;
    }

    if(cb.isChecked()==true){
        y*=2;
    }

    s1="Ответ: "+Double.toString(y);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблемы создают символы `<` и `>` попробуйте текст из ваших `RadioButton` прописать в `string` файле, и в `RadioButton` указать ссылку на `@string`

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли указать корневому тэгу в разметке эту строку

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Это - пространство имен `android`

Comment: не забыл, он там есть, просто неправильно отформатировал текст в блоке кода, сейчас исправил